# Refresh the contents of an eclipse preference page

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Can anyone please tell me how I can refresh a child page when its parent has been modified?

...in createContents() of the child preference page, I am listening on changes to the parent with this:

```
ParentPlugin.getDefault()
    .getPreferenceStore()
    .addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener()
    {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
        {
            //REFRESH CHILD PLUGIN
        };
    });
```

Comment: If you're finding that the contents of multiple pages are so closely connected that you need to do this, it may be better to simply put them on the same page.

Comment: @nitind There will be four other child pages depending on the value in parent page, hence I can't simply put it in the child page.

Comment: How about simple updating the child preference page by overriding the setVisible() method and perform any updates as needed?