# Eclipse RCP Preference page refresh issue

Tags: java, eclipse, refresh, preferences

I have a question similar to [Refresh the contents of an eclipse preference page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836387/refresh-the-contents-of-an-eclipse-preference-page)  but only similar, my problem doesn't include sub pages.

In a preference page, I have a combobox field editor, each value being linked to another preference page. I am hiding the preferences pages from the values not currently selected, to only have the currently selected value's attached preference page displayed.

I hide the preference pages while storing them in a HashMap, to readd them later :

```
PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager() ;
preferences.put(idPlugin, pm.remove(idPreferencesPage)) ;
```

Adding them back :

```
IPreferenceNode node = preferences.get(idPlugin) ;
if (node != null)
{
    PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager() ;
    pm.addToRoot(node);
    preferences.remove(idPlugin) ;
}
```

It almost works like a charm. The pages are removed, but adding them back doesn't trigger a refresh of the Preference dialog window, and I either need to attempt to set a "type filter text", and the list of preference pages is refreshed at that point.

Would anyone know of a way to force refresh the preferences dialog, rather than having to close it / open it, or filter/remove filter, to refresh ?