# How to link a parent preference page to a child preference page in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a preference page in Eclipse that contains a checkbox. This is the parent preference page.

The child preference page should contain different field editors based on some checkboxes values in the parent page.

Example: If checkbox in parent checked then create a text field in child.

I want to update/redraw the child page when I press apply.

I was trying to do this in the following way:

My child page class looks like this:

```
public class MyChildPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage
```

Overwritting setVisible method:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(final boolean visible)
{        
    super.setVisible(visible);        
    if (visible)
        createFieldEditors();            
}
```

My createFieldEditors method creates the fields using the same Composite everytime.

Still, no update is happening.

Is there a way to re-trigger preference page creation when changing the focus/visibility ?

This question was not answered and it is similar:
[Refresh the contents of an eclipse preference page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836387/refresh-the-contents-of-an-eclipse-preference-page)

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `FieldEditorPreferencePage#initialize()` instead?  That calls `load()` on each of the field editors.

Comment: It still doesn't call again the hole preference page initialization, I might add different fields...

Answer (score 0):

You should only create the field editors once.

You can override the `propertyChange` method of `FieldEditorPreferencePage` to be told about each preference property change:

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {

  String propertyId = event.getProperty();

  ... 

  super.propertyChange();
}
```

Comment: So, as a conclusion, preference pages cannot be created dinamically, fields can only be enabled/disabled based on other fields using a propertyChange, is this right ?

Comment: You can make fields not visible as well as disabled.